# How to add custom tags and application areas in Anylogic Cloud?

Tags: anylogic

How to add custom tags and application areas in Anylogic Cloud (under General info)? Some public models seems to have custom tags/application areas, but for me custom tags are just ignored (it accepts only the ones available from drop-down) after clicking Save. Is there any trick?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No problem here, I can easily type and add new tags:
[image]

Obviously, you can only do this on *your* models, so make sure you are logged in and use an up-to-date Chrome or Firefox...